# Lower the bitrate of a lossless m4a file

Tags: itunes, bitrate, alac

When I try to sync my music library to my iPod touch using iTunes it says that some songs can't be synchronized because the sample rate is too high. Indeed, some files have a bitrate of ~3000 kbps.

How can I convert theese m4a lossless files from 3000+kbps to 1411kbps?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac and want to lower the samplerate of existing files: [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html)

But generally **when importing your files to iTunes set the sample rate to 44.1 KHz** (lossles encoder window) because iPod / iPhone etc. can't handle - or at least don't allow - playback of sampling rates above 44.1K.

Here's a [Link](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12279?viewlocale=en_US) to the Apple Docs explaining the options for iTunes 11.